# My Money for Jam query - Download csv doesn't show Post name in the Post Link column

Tags: support, data-explorer

The [My Money for Jam](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8116/my-money-for-jam) query has a column called Post Link.

When I download the csv, that column only has a curly brace in it...

[image: link post column in excel sheet]

Answer (score 5):

**Make the row taller.**

The actual CSV looks like:

```
Post Link,Passive Rep Per Day,Passive Rep,Passive Up Reputation,Passive Down Reputation,Days Counted
"{
  ""title"": ""some title"",
  ""id"": some_id
}",<stats>
<etc>
```

That is, the value in each first column cell has a `{` immediately followed by a newline. So in Excel, with standard row height, you only see the `{`.

Comment: Thank you, @Aakashm, I hadn't thought if that. I looked at the row in the input area, and saw that there, too, there was only a curly brace. Apparently it has an enter after it, and that's why the rest of the content wasn't showing. Maybe the enter should be emitted when exporting to csv...